# Problemas com React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Boa tarde,

Estou recebendo um erro sempre que executo o comando `"react-native run-android"` para iniciar minha primeira aplicação no AVD com a versão 6.0 do android.
Sou iniciante em React Native, e gostaria de ajuda sobre o assunto.

Segui os passos conforme esse [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3cJwBh5e10) pede.

Erro que recebo na tela do smartphone emulado:

```
The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"originModulePath":"C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js","targetModuleName":"AccessibilityInfo","message":"Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`."}],"name":"Error","stack":"Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.\n    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph\\ModuleResolution.js:167:1306)\n    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph\\ResolutionRequest.js:80:16)\n    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph.js:237:485)\n    at Object.resolve (C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\lib\\transformHelpers.js:116:25)\n    at dependencies.map.result (C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:298:29)\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at resolveDependencies (C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:294:16)\n    at C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:159:33\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at step (C:\\Users\\neto_\\Google Drive\\Projetos\\ReactNative\\CozinheAgora\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:239:307)"}
processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:285
access$200
    BundleDownloader.java:37
onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:163
execute
    RealCall.java:153
run
    NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588
run
    Thread.java:818
```

Comment: Qual a versão do seu react-native?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1 e react-native: 0.56.0 @ThiagoTibau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem 5 possíveis soluções:

- **Atualize seu react-native**, algumas versões tem conflito com windows;
- **Faça downgrade do seu react-native:** Se o seu RN já estiver atualizado, faça downgrade, tem algumas versões que tem conflito com windows.
- **Reunicie seu computador:** pode parecer ridículo, porém, já tive esse erro que foi resolvido com o reinicio do computador;
- **Apague a pasta node_modules:** apague ela e reinstale os pacotes com o `npm install` ou `yarn install`
- **Realize os passos citados no erro:**

  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`

Comment: Tentei seguir todos os passos, mas continuo recebendo o mesmo erro.

Comment: Resolvi, fiz um downgrade da versão 0.56.0 para a 0.55.x do react-native e do babel para 4.x.x

Comment: A versão 0.55 e a 0.54 se não me engano tem conflito com o windows! Se puder marca a resposta ai! Abraços!